# How to use win32 API with C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winapi, mutex, semaphore

How to connect **win32** to **C#** and use win32 function for creating semaphore, mutex etc.

Comment: i try **using System.Runtime.InteropServices;** and **[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]** but i dont know  is  it right

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to use the Win32 API to use Mutexes or Semaphores. They already have .NET classes built in for that and have since version 1.1 for Mutex and 2.0 for Semaphore:

- [.NET Mutex Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx)
- [.NET Semaphore Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)

Some .NET internals to show that the Mutex class actually uses the Win32 API: Just as a quick sample, the code below is the decompiled source of the OpenMutex and ReleaseMutex methods from the Threading.Mutex class in .NET. It uses the DllImport attribute and extern keyword to gain access to functions in the kernel32.dll

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
internal static extern SafeWaitHandle OpenMutex(int desiredAccess, bool inheritHandle, string name);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.None)]
[ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
internal static extern bool ReleaseMutex(SafeWaitHandle handle);
```

You could use these snippets to do your exploring I suppose and much, much more info is available on this handy site: http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx

Comment: my task is write program wich implement Mutexes and Semaphores tasks using win32 and any programming language. I know Java but its hard to combinate win32 and java. I think C# is closer to Java and its easier to learn C# rather C++. So i want to know how to compine win32 and c#

Comment: Have you checked out the Java JNI? (Java Native Interface) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface  This might be a better way to go for you.

Comment: And... The .NET classes are actually wrappers around Win32 functions. It's a much simpler way of using those objects than trying to hit the Win32 API directly.

Comment: It's worth it? I assume C# is closer to win32 and it's stupid to use JNI and win32

Comment: Is it worth to write on c++ if main feature must be win32?

Comment: Check my most recent edit on the DllImport and extern stuff. Also check out this site: http://www.pinvoke.net/index.aspx

Answer (score 3):

C# provides its own methods for doing such things. you shouldn't have to mix Win32 and C# and it is definitely not recommended since .NET is meant to take over from Win32.

MSDN has an example on [how to use a mutex in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) ([and semaphores too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx)).

If you still wish to use .NET and Win32, you will have to use C++ with CLI enabled.